# About the definition of an oscillatory differential equation and Hill's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, spectral-theory, periodic-functions

My questions comes from reading the book The Spectral Theory of Periodic Differential Equations by Eastham.

Consider the following differential equation:

$[p(x)y'(x)]' + [\lambda s(x) + q(x)]y(x) = 0$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $p(x), s(x), q(x)$ are real valued, piece-wise continuous, and with period $a$. Also we assume that $s(x) \geq s>0$ and that $p(x)$ is never zero.

Now we can consider the periodic problem with the initial condtions that $y(a) = y(0), y'(a) = y'(0)$.

This problem is self adjoint, and the book states that there are an infinite countable eigenvalues, which can be ordered as such:

$\lambda_0 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2...$

[image]

**Question 1:**

Is this a complete characterization of the eigenvalues? That is, will every value of $\lambda$ for which there is a solution to the above equation with the above initial conditions be counted within that countable set?

Further down the book, he gives this definition:

The above differential equation is called **oscillatory** if it has a non-trivial solution with an infinite number of roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then this theorem follows:

If $\lambda > \lambda_0$ (from above), then the above equation is oscillatory.

[image]

**Question 2:**

How do I know that for every $\lambda$ there is a non-trivial solution to the equation? Can that equation be solved for any real valued $\lambda$ without specifying initial conditions?